# Why the statement did not return a result set for MS SQL jdbc 6.1.0

Tags: java, mssql-jdbc, callable-statement

I have to execute transaction query in java for MS SQL to update value in row and return updated result in java. I'm using the next code. It works fine for mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8 but I have exception for mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8. Can you please explain how to fix this in java for 6.1 version?

```
String sql = "BEGIN\n" +
        "   BEGIN TRANSACTION\n" +
        "   declare @i bigint = -1\n" +
        "   UPDATE tableWithUniqueIds WITH(UPDLOCK)\n" +
        "   SET    @i = currentValue = (currentValue + 1)\n" +
        "   SELECT @i\n" +
        "   COMMIT\n" +
        "   END";
try(Connection con = getConnection(); CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall(sql);) {

stmt.setQueryTimeout(1000);

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
...
} catch(Exception ex) {
...
} finally {
...
}
```

Exception:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:206) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:464) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:405) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7535) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2438) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:208) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:183) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar:?]
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:317) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.1.0.jre8.jar:?]
...
```

Comment: `Connection#prepareCall` is intended to be used for calling stored procedures, not executing the SQL code from a stored procedure directly in Java.  Whether or not your code used to work with a different driver, it isn't proper usage of this API, from what I can see.

Comment: #Tim Biegeleisen is it possible to execute my sql code in Java without storing it in database?

Comment: Yes, but the JDBC API usually only allows one statement to be executed at a time.  If you want to execute two statements in a single transaction, this is also possible.